# PreparedStatement automatically adds the \

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make a query using the PreparedStatemant:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_GET_PROCS_DT_LOG = "(SELECT concat(date_format(max(dt_start),'%Y-%m-%d'),'%') FROM table)";

 PreparedStatement statement = s.getConnection().prepareStatement(GET_PROCS.replaceFirst("<dtLOG>","?"));
statement.setObject(1,  DEFAULT_GET_PROCS_DT_LOG);
rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

In the debug I notice the query became like this:

```
...WHERE condition like '(SELECT concat(date_format(max(dt_start),\'%Y-%m-%d\'),\'%\') FROM table)'
```

instead to be:

```
...WHERE condition like (SELECT concat(date_format(max(dt_start),'%Y-%m-%d'),'%') FROM table)
```

so I always get null in the result set, I tried to put the entire sql script in the prepareStatement (without ?) and it works, so the problem is when I use setString or setObject (I tried both).

Does anyone know the solution???

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Which programming environment?

Comment: I believe that is one of the *features* of `statement.setObject(` - also one reason to use `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL injection - it is not expected to add SQL statements or part of one as *values* to a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @jarlh Mysql with java

Comment: @user16320675 so what should i do to avoid it add the \, i tried both setObject and setString

Comment: do not use any of these setter methods to add SQL statement (parts); use these only for values - change the SQL so that it can be controlled by values (if possible); or use simple string concatenation of replacement (considering the SQL injection problem)

Comment: @user16320675 that is a bad suggestion. PreparedStatement features help to avoid security vulnerabilities. Using string concatenation is opening a query to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: You cannot use prepared statements to set subqueries on a parameter. You can only use it to set **values** on a parameter.

Comment: @aled - that is not correct, or better, only applies to user input (or similar) being concatenated to the statement - but not to statement components provided by source being concatenated (I believe I added something about considering SQL injection... even about it being a reason for using `PreparedStatement`...)